# CSS/JS Can I transition an image's position if it moves due to previous elements being removed from flow?

Tags: javascript, css, transition

So I'm trying to implement a gallery as in this [link](https://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page228/standout) (hit live demo and scroll down). When a user clicks a button the images that aren't in that group should shrink and disappear and the other images should move to fill the gaps. At the moment I am using a grid to hold the images. Each image is positioned statically but with a top and left set by JS based on it's offsetTop and OffsetLeft. To hide each image I am setting it's position to absolute to remove it from the flow and setting transform: scale(0) with a transition on transform that works perfectly AND the images that remain relocate to the right spot in the grid. However they obviously do this instantaneously which is not the outcome I'm after. I really want to stick to basic HTML CSS JS for this project as I'm learning a lot doing it. I just want to know if there is an easy solution I'm missing or is it going to get very complicated? [Here](https://shootersf.github.io/Front-End-Demo/) is my current version so you can see where I'm at.

Here is some of the JS trying to solve the problem:

```
//adds galleryButtonClicked function to all gallery buttons
(function() {
    let galleryButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery-button");
    for (let i = 0; i < galleryButtons.length; i++)
    {
        galleryButtons[i].addEventListener("click", galleryButtonClicked);
    }
})();

//adds top and left to each gallery image that matches it's current position. Declared and called
//seperately as may need to recall on window resize
function setImageAbsCoords() {
    let images = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery-image");
    for (let image of images)
    {
        let y = image.offsetTop + "px";
        let x = image.offsetLeft + "px";

        image.style.top = y;
        image.style.left = x;
    }
}
setImageAbsCoords();

function galleryButtonClicked() {
    //show only group images
    if (this.dataset.group == 0)
        showAllGalleryImages();
    else
        showGalleryImagesGroup(this.dataset.group);
}

function showAllGalleryImages() {
    let images = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery-image");
    for (let image of images)
    {
        showGalleryImage(image);
    }
}

function showGalleryImagesGroup(group) {
    let images = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery-image");
    for (let image of images)
    {
        if (image.dataset.group === group)
            showGalleryImage(image);
        else
            hideGalleryImage(image);
    }
}

function showGalleryImage(image) {
    image.style.position = "static";
    image.style.transform = "scale(1)";
}

function hideGalleryImage(image) {
    image.style.position = "absolute";
    image.style.transform = "scale(0)";

}
```

and the respective CSS:

```
gallery-image-container {
    display: grid;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 3rem 0;
    width: 80%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 170px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
    gap: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
}

.gallery-image {
    transition : transform 400ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Finally, the html in question:

```
<div class="grid gallery-buttons">
                <button class="button gallery-button active" data-group="0">All</button>
                <button class="button gallery-button" data-group="1">Lorem Ipsum</button>
                <button class="button gallery-button" data-group="2">Dolor Sit</button>
                <button class="button gallery-button" data-group="3">adipiscing Elit</button>
            </div>
            <div class="grid gallery-image-container">
                <img class="gallery-image" data-group="1" src="https://picsum.photos/170/170?image=0" alt="random demo-gallery-pic">
                <img class="gallery-image" data-group="3" src="https://picsum.photos/170/170?image=11" alt="random demo-gallery-pic">
                <img class="gallery-image" data-group="1" src="https://picsum.photos/170/170?image=15" alt="random demo-gallery-pic">
                <img class="gallery-image" data-group="1" src="https://picsum.photos/170/170?image=18" alt="random demo-gallery-pic">
                <img class="gallery-image" data-group="3" src="https://picsum.photos/170/170?image=23" alt="random demo-gallery-pic">
                <img class="gallery-image" data-group="2" src="https://picsum.photos/170/170?image=27" alt="random demo-gallery-pic">
                <img class="gallery-image" data-group="2" src="https://picsum.photos/170/170?image=30" alt="random demo-gallery-pic">
                <img class="gallery-image" data-group="1" src="https://picsum.photos/170/170?image=31" alt="random demo-gallery-pic">
                <img class="gallery-image" data-group="3" src="https://picsum.photos/170/170?image=38" alt="random demo-gallery-pic">
                <img class="gallery-image" data-group="2" src="https://picsum.photos/170/170?image=42" alt="random demo-gallery-pic">
                <img class="gallery-image" data-group="2" src="https://picsum.photos/170/170?image=55" alt="random demo-gallery-pic">
                <img class="gallery-image" data-group="1" src="https://picsum.photos/170/170?image=69" alt="random demo-gallery-pic">
            </div>
```

Comment: The only way I know of to not make it instant is to use height and width properties on a regular image tag, and not use transform or position styling. Why do you need to use absolute? Do you have a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I'm new to this jsfiddle stuff but I copied in the parts of my code that are the issue. If you hit the "lorem ipsum" button you will see images fade out and be replaced by the remaining ones but I want the remaining ones to transition into their spots at the same speed as the ones fading out take to disappear...
https://jsfiddle.net/o3dxzkhu/3/

Comment: You are required to post your markup and code here, within your quesiton, and not a jsfiddle. [mcve] A fiddle can compliment your example but not be used in its stead.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Read the first sentence of "Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some. " and completely skipped the second one for some reason. I'll edit in the old code for posterity. I'm new to all this. Thanks for setting me straight.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I actually figured this out. I've [included a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shootersf/5kts69zv/2/) that demos it working properly. Just had to translate the images back to their initial positions with transform turned off and then set translate to none with it back on. Thanks to anyone that took the time to read this.

```
//adds galleryButtonClicked function to all gallery buttons
(function() {
    let galleryButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery-button");
    for (let i = 0; i < galleryButtons.length; i++)
    {
        galleryButtons[i].addEventListener("click", galleryButtonClicked);
    }
})();

//adds top and left to each gallery image that matches it's current position. Declared and called
//seperately as may need to recall on window resize
function setImageAbsCoords() {
    let images = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery-image");
    for (let image of images)
    {
        //for later do not update if already set to absolute position
        if (image.style.position !== "absolute")
        {
            let y = image.offsetTop + "px";
            let x = image.offsetLeft + "px";

            image.style.top = y;
            image.style.left = x;
        }
    }
}
setImageAbsCoords();

function galleryButtonClicked() {
    //gather images old positions
    let images = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery-image");
    console.log(images.length);
    for (let image of images) 
    {
        image.dataset.oldposx = image.offsetLeft;
        image.dataset.oldposy = image.offsetTop;
    }

    //show only group images
    if (this.dataset.group == 0)
        showAllGalleryImages();
    else
        showGalleryImagesGroup(this.dataset.group);

    let staticImages = Array.from(images).filter(img => img.style.position === "static");
    transitionRemainingImagesToNewPos(staticImages);

}
function showAllGalleryImages() {
    let images = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery-image");
    for (let image of images)
    {
        showGalleryImage(image);
    }
}

function showGalleryImagesGroup(group) {
    let images = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery-image");
    for (let image of images)
    {
        if (image.dataset.group === group)
            showGalleryImage(image);
        else
            hideGalleryImage(image);
    }
}

function showGalleryImage(image) {
    //set wasHidden flag for transitionRemainingImagesToNewPost to reset scale before turning off transitions
    if (image.style.position === "absolute")
        image.dataset.wasHidden = true;
    else
        image.dataset.wasHidden = false;

    image.style.position = "static";
    image.style.transform = "scale(1)";
}

function hideGalleryImage(image) {
    image.style.position = "absolute";
    image.style.transform = "scale(0)";
}

function transitionRemainingImagesToNewPos(images) {
    for (let image of images)
    {
        //turn off transitions
        image.classList.add("no-transition");
        //move back to old position before gallery reshaped after button press
        diffx = image.dataset.oldposx - image.offsetLeft;
        diffy = image.dataset.oldposy - image.offsetTop;
        image.style.transform = `translate(${diffx}px, ${diffy}px)`;
        //set scale back to 0 if had been hidden before now
        if (image.dataset.wasHidden === 'true')
            image.style.transform += ` scale(0)`;

        image.offsetHeight; //force a redraw
        image.classList.remove("no-transition");
        image.style.transform = "none";
    }
    //update top and left to new position
    setImageAbsCoords();
}
```